# can't run a simple program in CLion

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clion

I'm VERY new to CLion so please be gentle :) 
I took a project I did for a programming course I'm taking, I managed to build it, but when I tried to run it the CLion just freezes. I tried to run it in debug mode, but no success there either - it waits for a few seconds and then I recieve a message: "command timed out".

I thought the problem might be in my program, so I wrote a simple "Hello World" program - still no success.

few technical specs that might help:
I use CLion 1.2.1 (Newest version).
For my toolchains I use TDM-GCC compiler (downloaded from here: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) - I actually do not use the newest version - I use version 4.9.2-3 instead -  because I wanted the GDB to be 7.8 so Clion supports it).

My computer runs windows 10 (64 bit), intel core i5-4210U, 8 GB RAM (for what it's worth...)

hope you could help me.

Comment: Do you have Avast antivirus running?

Comment: yes... does it have anything to do with it.....?

Comment: Yes, maybe changing its setting as you can find here [Stop avast! from attacking my own programs](http://superuser.com/questions/555905/stop-avast-from-attacking-my-own-programs) can help... If not, add some exceptions or disable it while running your programs...

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avast antivirus running … changing its setting as you can find here [Stop avast! from attacking my own programs](http://superuser.com/questions/555905/stop-avast-from-attacking-my-own-programs) can help...
                    – nnn